# Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. Show that for all integer $a$ such that $a^{pq} \equiv a^p + a^q - a \pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. Show that for all integer $a$ such that 
$$a^{pq} \equiv a^p + a^q - a \pmod{pq}$$
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sufficient to show that the congruence is valid for mod p and mod q. By Fermat's little   theorem for prime $p$ have $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p} $. This follow $a^{pq}\equiv a^q\pmod{p} $ and so $a^{pq}\equiv a^p+a^q-a\pmod{p}. $